# How to remove borders around textbox when adding background imageI have

Tags: html, css

I have a textbox of which by I removed the default borders using    `outline:none;`  However, when I add a background-image the border is shown and can't be removed!

How do I get rid of this? Here is the box:

```
<input type = "text" placeholder = "Username" class = "txt_input">
```

and the css:

```
background: url('images/user-icon.png') left no-repeat;
margin-bottom: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
font-family: 'ProximaNova-Bold';
outline: none;
width: 200px;
height:30px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: capitalize;
padding:15px;
padding-left:21px;
```

Comment: Just add border:none;

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using box-shadow as a border here?

Comment: @Pawan border:none didn't work

Comment: @cimmanon I'm using box-shadow to achieve the thin border effect

Comment: @GIVENALITY see this link http://jsfiddle.net/grYsD/

Comment: @GIVENALITY Your box-shadow border isn't any thinner than a 1px solid border:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/0vnwpc0k

Comment: @Pawan I love it. Let me apply it! Thanks

Comment: @cimmanon  Thanks, I didn't know so. Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

add a `border: 0px none;` to your css? The outline handles only the focus border.

Comment: Providing a demo really helps bring attention to your answer:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/rcrgim2i

Comment: 0px is not valid CSS. You should just do `border: 0;`

Comment: @Henridv It seems to validate just fine to me.  The border-width doesn't matter in this instance because the border-style is set to none.

Comment: @cimmanon Oh indeed. For some reason I thought that `0px` was not valid. Anyway, since 0 is 0 in all units, it makes more sense to me to drop the `px` part :). Which the CSS validator also does (http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Comment: You're all right with leaving out the px part. `border:none;` is enough. But this also needs to be human readable and for that reasons I always use the full notation even in CSS - just for my soft compiler between my ears ...

Answer (score 2):

Use `border:none` instead of `outline:none`. Also, to capitalize text, use `text-transform:uppercase`. Note: you will remain with a little border, because of the box-shadow you applied. Removing this also will leave you with no border.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think  `border: transparent;` is better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried  this `border:0;` on your CSS style??

Answer (score -1):

i use 'vscode' and on mine i had to combine (below)

*

border: none;
outline: none;

*

copy that and it should work hopefully

Comment: Hi gee. Thanks for your answer, however I think this should already be covered by [Jeroen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16791185/4252741). If his answer works for you it's helpful to upvote it.